# Pandas update a dataframe by looking up the column names and values from another dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have an excel sheet that I read into a pandas dataframe. it looks like:

```
KEY_FIELD_NAME  KEY_FIELD_VAL_ORIG     KEY_FIELD_VAL_NEW
 NAME              XXX                      YYY
 AGE               11                       22  
 INCOME            100                      200
 NAME               ABC                    DEF
```

I have another pandas dataframe (df_orig) like this:

```
NAME AGE INCOME
XXX   11  100
ABC   25   300
```

How can I update the df_orig so that it will automatically lookup the excel sheet by KEY_FIELD_NAME  and KEY_FIELD_VAL_ORIG and update to the new value:

df_orig_want:

```
NAME AGE INCOME
YYY  22   200
DEF   25   300
```

Comment: What do the rest of the rows look like?

Comment: Thank you Andy. You mean in which dataframe? df_orig?

Comment: the one with KEY_FIELD_NAME

Comment: @AndyHayden: The rest of rows have repeated KEY_FIELD_NAME but different values of KEY_FIELD_VAL_ORIG and KEY_FIELD_VAL_NEW

Comment: could you edit in another  set of rows? i think that changes the potential answers significantly.

Comment: Thanks, I did. The columns not mentioned in KEY_FIELD_NAME remains unchanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you would like to use [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html), but before you can use it, you should reshape your modifying dataframe to have the same shape as the original `DataFrame` by using [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with the original name as index so we can later join on that:

```
df['NAME'] = pd.Series(np.where(df['KEY_FIELD_NAME'] == 'NAME', df['KEY_FIELD_VAL_ORIG'],np.nan)).ffill()
df_piv = df.pivot(index='NAME', columns='KEY_FIELD_NAME', values='KEY_FIELD_VAL_NEW')
print(df_piv)
#    KEY_FIELD_NAME  AGE INCOME NAME
#NAME                           
#ABC             NaN    NaN  DEF
#XXX              22    200  YYY
```

and then you can immediately call update after setting index. It works inplace, so

```
df_orig.set_index('NAME', drop=False, inplace=True)
df_orig.update(df_piv)
print(df_orig.reset_index(drop=True))
#      NAME AGE INCOME
#0  YYY  22    200
#1  DEF  25    300
```

Comment: That was pure genius. Thank you.